# how to let the sticky navbar be above all the elements in the page?

Tags: html, css, angular

How to let the elements in the page go under the sticky navbar when scrolling down and not above it and hide it ?
I copied the code from w3 schools to my Angular project but when i scroll down, all the elements go above the navbar and it hides it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to probably add a z-index to the navbar to make it present on the foremost layer of the screen.

Have a look at this link for a much deeper information on the same.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index